# Getting Applications location in Automator

Tags: automator

How do I get the directory where the app created in automator resides?

Example:

- Create App using automator
- Save to ~/Documents/Automator
- Run automator app, which does something in it's directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an AppleScript step which contains:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set p to POSIX path of (path to me)
    return {p}

    return input
end run
```

From there, you can use the "p" parameter.